# http request should be redirect to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, https

I have Installed SSL on my server.
So request are `https` by default.

- But when I enter Url `http://example.com/abc/a` it redirects to
  `https://example.com` it should be go to (`https://example.com/abc/a`).
- And when I tried with exact secure Url `https://example.com/abc/a` it
  redirects to same.

I want to solve my first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following code at top of your **.htaccess** file, if you are using Magento

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown what you have in your `.htaccess` file but I use the following to redirect all standard http traffic to https.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I have use this. i redirects to homepage

Comment: For example:  remove httts from current url it redirects to current page with https.But in my case it redirects to homepage with https.It should be redirect to current page with https

Comment: I guess there could be something else in the htaccess file that contradicts the above directives - or perhaps magento itself has some mechanism in place to deal with https?

Comment: I don't know what is reason. i have used sub domain